# Echo part of two dimentional json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, jsondecoder

I have a nested json array at

```
$sdata['my_server']['server_ips'];
```

Whose result looks like this

```
{ "ip_address": [ { "access": "private", "address": "x.x.x.x", "family": "IPv4" }, { "access": "public", "address": "xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx", "family": "IPv6" }, { "access": "public", "address": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "family": "IPv4", "part_of_plan": "yes" } ] }
```

I only want t show value of ipv4 ip address in access public part means this one

```
"address": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Is there any idea on it? Thanks

Comment: And what is your exact problem, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` with `json_decode`

```
 $r = array_filter(json_decode($json, true)['ip_address'], function($v){
  return ($v['family'] === 'IPv4' && $v['access'] === 'public');
 });
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/k0M0V

`print_r($r)` will give you an array, you can use `array_shift` and than use `$r['address']`. If there are multiple values than use `array_column` by `address` and use `implode`.